# checking status of an uploading file using google drive api .net

Tags: c#, .net, google-drive-api

I am writing an application to check the status of an uploading file. The file wont be upload by the application but will be uploaded by `google drive` itself. This is my question - is there any way to `monitor` the status of a `file` uploaded by `google drive` desktop application using `google drive api` or by any other means. By any other means I meant that, maybe `google drive` application might be creating a file for writing `upload status` in the computer itself. If there is a `file` like that please tell me how to access that file.

Comment: I don't really know what to try with google-drive api. But in the local system i found a file snapshot.db in Appdata/Local/Google/Drive. I found that the file is a SQLlite database and contains information of all the files in google drive. I haven't got time to research more on this database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, there is no current documented and supported way of doing this using the Drive API. There are other options open to you (see comments), but none using the Drive API.

Comment: "There are other options open to you (see comments)" what comments?
Do you mean verify the "Appdata/Local/Google/Drive" and the snapshot.db file to check status?